# Using NSFetchedResultsController's cache when synchronizing with a web service

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple app that uses core data to persist data fetched on the web. I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a`UITableView` with that data. I am using a cache on the `NSFetchedResultsController`s results set like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"MyCache"];
```

Is there a way to invalidate the cache when I update my data model when synchronizing with a web service? Or shouldn't I be using any cache at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to delete the cache just because you synchronised data. You only need to delete the cache (using `deleteCacheWithName:`) when you change the fetch request predicate / sort. Synchronisation changes will simply update the controller and update the cache.

You don't want to use a cache if you change the fetch predicate / sort frequently.